# DL4006 warning: Set the SHELL option -o pipefail before RUN with a pipe in it

Tags: dockerfile, lint, hadolint

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM strimzi/kafka:0.20.1-kafka-2.6.0

USER root:root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium
# Download, unpack, and place the debezium-connector-postgres folder into the /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium directory
RUN curl -s https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-postgres/1.7.0.Final/debezium-connector-postgres-1.7.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz | tar xvz --transform 's/debezium-connector-postgres/debezium/' --directory /opt/kafka/plugins/
USER 1001
```

When I use [hadolint](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) on it by

```
hadolint Dockerfile
```

I got warning

> Dockerfile:6 DL4006 warning: Set the SHELL option -o pipefail before RUN with a pipe in it. If you are using /bin/sh in an alpine image or if your shell is symlinked to busybox then consider explicitly setting your SHELL to /bin/ash, or disable this check

I know I have a pipe `|` in the line started with `RUN`.

However, I still really don't know how to fix based on this warning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oh, just found the solution in the wiki page at https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL4006

Here is my fixed version:

```
FROM strimzi/kafka:0.20.1-kafka-2.6.0

USER root:root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium
# Download, unpack, and place the debezium-connector-postgres folder into the /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium directory
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN curl -s https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-postgres/1.7.0.Final/debezium-connector-postgres-1.7.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz | tar xvz --transform 's/debezium-connector-postgres/debezium/' --directory /opt/kafka/plugins/
USER 1001
```

The reason adding `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]` is at https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices.md#using-pipes

Below is a copy:

---

Some `RUN` commands depend on the ability to pipe the output of one command into another, using the pipe character (`|`), as in the following example:

```
RUN wget -O - https://some.site | wc -l > /number
```

Docker executes these commands using the `/bin/sh -c` interpreter, which only
evaluates the exit code of the last operation in the pipe to determine success.
In the example above this build step succeeds and produces a new image so long
as the `wc -l` command succeeds, even if the `wget` command fails.

If you want the command to fail due to an error at any stage in the pipe,
prepend `set -o pipefail &&` to ensure that an unexpected error prevents the
build from inadvertently succeeding. For example:

```
RUN set -o pipefail && wget -O - https://some.site | wc -l > /number
```

> Not all shells support the `-o pipefail` option.
>
> In cases such as the `dash` shell on
> Debian-based images, consider using the *exec* form of `RUN` to explicitly
> choose a shell that does support the `pipefail` option. For example:
>
> ```
> RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "set -o pipefail && wget -O - https://some.site | wc -l > /number"]
> ```

Comment: How would you set multiple values, such as `pipefail` and `nounset`, without the repeating the `set` command? (as you are instead passing these as an ` -o` flag to the shell directly)

Comment: The suggestion to use `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]` is not covered there though, but much appreciated that you did it.  See also https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/7489#issuecomment-816858450 , https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell